# JSF - <h:outputText> (escape special chars)

Tags: java, jsf, facelets

I am trying set 1<sup>®</sup>2 in outputText:

```
<h:outputText value="1&lt;sup&gt;&#174;&lt;sup/&gt;2" escape="false"/>
```

What is incorrect? I get `2` in uppercase.

Comment: 2 is number, how can it be in upper case?

Comment: I am sorry. I get R in degree 2.

Comment: why not just copy `1®2` and paste in your XHTML and save it with UTF-8 in efitor

Comment: You don't need `<h:outputText>` at all. You can just write down HTML and plaintext directly in JSF page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can choose one of the following

In your original proposal you had a misplace the `/` it should be before the `sup`

```
<h:outputText value="1&lt;sup&gt;&#174;&lt;/sup&gt;2" escape="false"/>
```

You can also remove the `sup` completely  (but than your (R) wont be small)

```
<h:outputText value="1&#174;2" escape="false"/>
```

Finally you can use it directly without escaping

```
<h:outputText value="1®2"/>
```