# using <> characters in value attribute of h:link in jsf

Tags: jsf, xhtml

I want to add `<wbr>` to value attribute of `<h:link>`. so I wrote this:

```
<h:link value="THIS-IS-LONG<wbr>-WORD" outcome="word"></h:link>
```

I want to create this html:

```
<a href="/demo/word.xhtml">THIS-IS-LONG<wbr>-WORD</a>
```

but I got this error:

```
HTTP Status 500 - Error Parsing /index.xhtml: Error Traced[line: 330] The value of attribute "value" associated with an element type "h:link" must not contain the '<' character.
```

how can I add  to value?

I am using

```
Server version Apache Tomcat/8.0.27
OS Name Linux-4.12.3-1-MANJARO
JVM Version 1.8.0_121-b13
Mojarra 2.2.12
```

Comment: Search the internet and use in your query the term 'escaping'  ("xhtml escape lessthan"  (the <) might work). And by using the tag `wbr` you sort of say it works when using `<p>`

Comment: @Kukeltje thanks for your comment. I think you mean &lt;wbr&gt;. I tried it and text of link generated like THIS-IS-LONG<wbr>-WORD. I mean <wbr> becomes text not tag. I want to add <wbr> as a tag.

Comment: No I did not mean that.... I meant this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14374758/jsf-houtputtext-escape-special-chars

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved by using `<h:link>` and `<h:outputText>` together.

```
<h:link outcome="word"><h:outputText value="THIS-IS-LONG&lt;wbr /&gt;-WORD" escape="false"></h:outputText></h:link>
```